# Is the Indicator documentation removed?

Tags: indicator

At the start of the week I started developing my indicator program and the documentation has disappeared since then. Is there plans to remove the functionality or something like that?

Comment: Can you give me the URL you were using please ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/python/AppIndicator3-0.1.html Is the one I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most links for indicator API/documentation are dead, but I have managed to find a few [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/491886/67335).