# AppIndicator documentation for Python

Tags: unity, python, indicator

Where has the documentation for the Python bindings to AppIndicator gone?

Visiting [this](https://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/) official looking page, all the links are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some links I've managed to find are...

- http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/AppIndicator3_0.1/classes/Indicator.html
- http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-12.04/python/AppIndicator3-0.1.html
- http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/c/AppIndicator3-0.1.html
- http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-14.04

Comment: And now... all this is dead as well. WTF Ubuntu?? Y U NO preserve API docs?!

Comment: @ulidtko You may yet be able to Google the API and look at the cached versions.  Regardless, I found looking at the source of existing indicators to learn how to write my own.  Check out [this list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I found [this really nice post](https://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html), and [here's mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019304/whats-up-with-ubuntu-desktop-api-docs-why-are-all-the-appindicator-links-dead) take on the "docs are totally dead" problem.

Comment: I hear you fellas. What a joke.

Answer (score 2):

Since all these links are dead now, nowadays you can find the reference manual here:

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#AyatanaAppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html