# What's up with Ubuntu Desktop API docs? Why are all the AppIndicator links dead?

Tags: 16.04, application-development, indicator, documentation

I was going to make a quick tray monitoring script. Y'know, the classic CPU/mem/net usage example; I need a similar thing, but with my own code.

15 minutes later, trying to find any doc whatsoever for the `AppIndicator` API, I'm raging in frustration. [Dead¹](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-14.04) [links²](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/c/AppIndicator3-0.1) [all over³](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/AppIndicator3_0.1/classes/Indicator.html) [the⁴](https://launchpad.net/giraffe) [space⁵](http://blog.strycore.com/2010/01/using-the-application-indicator-in-python/).

The whole https://developer.ubuntu.com site? Looks like a joke. Desktop development no more, nobody uses that ancient tech. [Go fancy yourself](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=appindicator+site%3Adeveloper.ubuntu.com&t=canonical&ia=web), dear indicator developer:

[image: no results screenshot]

... Is there anything I could do to reality-check this tragic situation?

I figure, the specific API I'm looking for could probably be pulled out of Wayback archive or something; but you see, there's a bigger problem here. API docs are not supposed to vanish like this. It's simply **unusable**.

Please share if anyone has the recipes to build the `gtk-doc`s (or `gir` docs, or whatever they're called) from source. Or if you can ping a relevant person for this: please do.

Comment: Okay [here is one](http://web.archive.org/web/20160502231436/http://developer.ubuntu.com:80/api/devel/ubuntu-12.04/python/AppIndicator-0.1.html) hit on Wayback. [Here is another (13.04)](http://web.archive.org/web/20160521081328/http://developer.ubuntu.com:80/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/python/AppIndicator3-0.1.html). Doesn't answer my question though.

Comment: An alive blogpost, very helpful refresher indeed https://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the rudeness.

Comment: There's also http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#AppIndicator3-0.1 which holds the API docs for all Gobject introspection packages.

Answer (score 5):

As you may have heard, in April 2017, Canonical announced that Unity and all related projects were being abandoned. This includes indicators, which were an Ubuntu specific project. As such, during the last 12 months, several parts of that, which were hosted by Canonical, have been taken down or removed from web sites, including developer documentation.

However, that documentation was simply styled to match the web site, and is the same documentation that is in the source code, and shipped in the packaging. Simply install the `libappindicator-doc` package, and you will have a local copy of the documentation. If you want it to be a little easier to browse, you can also consider installing the `devhelp` package.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but I converted these docs many years ago, and they are not perfect - https://docs.ubuntu.com/phone/en/

I hope it helps.

@dobey is correct, the team that built this left in 2017 and the work was archived.