# Can't find doc package for libappindicator

Tags: apt, indicator

I am trying to make a simple indicator (a simple bar to show current brightness of screen) for my system tray with `appindicator3`. The problem is that none of the two tutorials that I found on the subject cover it, and I can't find any documentation about `appindicator3`. This issue has already been detected in the comments of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/491886).

I thought my search had ended when I found `libappindicator-doc` and installed it,

```
apt-get install libappindicator-doc
```

However, there is nothing useful under `/usr/share/doc/libappindicator-doc`, just a changelog and a copyright.

Did I look in the wrong place? Never before have I found a useless `/usr/share/doc/package-doc` directory once installed the `package-doc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do `$ dpkg -L libappindicator-doc` to know that the documentation is in `/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/` :

Snippet

```
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/annotation-glossary.html
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/api-index-0-5.html
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/api-index-deprecated.html
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/api-index-full.html
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/ch01.html
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/index.html
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/libappindicator-app-indicator.html
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/libappindicator.devhelp2
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libappindicator/object-tree.html
```